# Stuck at 3 million border mark minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I was daring and went past the 3 million mark on one of the private servers i play on and now can't get back to spawn because it keeps kicking me with "illegal Position" as its reason. Is there any way I can get back to spawn?

Comment: ask the admin to reposition you via your player file. Or if they can TP you if you can login.

Comment: How did you manage to get there in the first place?

Answer (score 9):

You will need to get the server owner to either use a program to move you back into the playable area, or delete your player file so you spawn back at the world spawnpoint.

[MCEdit](https://khroki.github.io/MCEdit-Unified/) is a third party program capable of opening world files and moving players.

For the deletion method, your player data will be stored as a file with the name as your UUID in the "playerdata" folder of the world file. Note that deleting this will also remove your inventory (I'm guessing you're using commands and or creative mode anyway if you got past the 30 million mark).

Comment: I suggest NBTExplorer as that lets you edit the NBT data in the player file. And it's lighter than MCEdit for simple tasks like relocating or altering player data. Also, there are many other (an in some cases better) alternatives to MCEdit....but that's my opinion just as MCEdit is probably yours :) Also, doesn't MCEdit require shutting down the server first? Not a good chance an admin would do that? NBTEdit only edits 1 file at a time (well, unless you open more than one)  and that can be done while the player is offline without taking down the server or deleting the player data.

Comment: @ydobonebi Didn't realise NBTEdit could work without shutting down the server. That's certainly the better choice then.

Comment: at worse, the changes won't persist until restart, but Im pretty sure it loads the playerfile when they login. Eitherway, no immediate shutdown required.

Answer (score -4):

Either teleport or kill yourself is what I would do.

Comment: Except he/she can't do anything because he/she keeps getting kicked.

Comment: Please re-read the question. They say they are on a private server. Chances are they don't have personal access to teleport and the kill command is also typically restricted.

Comment: I am op but when I try to type /kill, it will kick me beforehand